# How does Google crawl a dynamic page?

Tags: html, seo

I specifically mean a dynamic page that depends on GET variable. My website holds most of the data in a database, and depending on GET variable, it prints different results. How do I make it so that Google can see all results in database and index them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Google crawl a dynamic page?

The same way as any other page

> I specifically mean a dynamic page that depends on GET variable.

If you have a single variable, then it probably won't cause any issues. Having lots of parameters in the query string can cause Google to decide it is probably not a useful page to crawl.

> How do I make it so that Google can see all results in database and index them??

Link to them.

Comment: Well, it's a website that runs on my framework, which has only few pages and all the content is stored in database. So if I have a list of links to all pages with all possible variables, Google will index them?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the content is stored. Client asks server for resource. Server gives client resource. The client cannot know and does not care how the server decided what data to return as the resource.

Comment: i can get only css or js file only when crawl the dynamic web page

Answer (score 1):

To have google index all of your results, create a sitemap.xml of all your links and place it at the root of your website. If you have a lot of links / pages to set, maybe make a function in php that automatically makes the sitemap.xml. There are plugins to wordpress that do this, maybe download one and have a look at the source if you need an example.